# Does boost library really supports Unicode under Windows?

Tags: windows, boost, unicode

Under Windows the only way to get Unicode support is to use `wchar_t` (UTF-16 under Windows) instead of `char`.

The problem is that I found that at least one of the boost libraries (`boost::program_options`) doesn't support Unicode at all: you are not able to compile the examples as Unicode.

Shouldn't boost be able to compiled with wide strings? - I would even expect this to be the default behavior under Windows.

Comment: Does http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id1420791 not help?

Comment: It seems there is a new discussion about this in the new boost 1_43_0

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options/design.html#program_options.design.unicode